# Providing a Discriminated Union from an F# Type Provider

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-3.0

I've gotten the basics of type providers such as creating a type

```
let thisAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
let t = ProvidedTypeDefinition(
           thisAssembly,namespaceName,
           xType.Attribute(xname "name").Value,
           baseType = Some typeof<obj>)
```

but I need to be able to define record types and DU types is there any way to do this with type providers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to define any F# specific types like Discriminated Unions, Records, or Modules, in a type provider, only classes and namespaces, which is a bit unfortunate

Comment: Is this CLR limitation? I mean classes are so restricting in functional languages. Records would be more natural result of SQL queries for instance.

Comment: No, it is not a CLR limitation. Recently, proposals have been accepted to allow provided types to be records and DUs. Not sure they’ll be there before F# 8, but who knows.

Comment: @Abel any links to that proposal so that we can follow the progress?