# How do you provide a discriminated union from an F# type provider

Tags: f#, type-providers, discriminated-union

Is it possible to emit a discriminated union type from an F# type provider? If so, is there any sample code available for doing so?

Comment: I do not think this is currently possible, but I might be wrong..

Comment: No, it's not possible. Already asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20421160/providing-a-discriminateunion/20471642#20471642

Comment: Well, there's at least no straight-forward way to do it. At the assembly level, DUs are just class hierarchies with special attributes and methods. Maybe there's more to it than that, I'm unsure. But you would have to generate everything "correctly", including overloading `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` and all that jazz or risk chaos, so you would basically be rewriting part of the F# compiler. I think that's probably the reason it's not included in the `ProvidedTypes` API as of yet.

Comment: @luksan - sadly there's also some additional metadata that the compiler uses to tell true DUs from merely DU-like types, and that metadata is impossible to include with a provided type.

Comment: the Fil project can build F# compatible DU types at runtime using reflection emit, they are compatible as far as they are usable via F#'s reflection module, I'm not sure if this would be compatible with a type provider, but the code is available here (in the MakeUnion function): https://fil.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Fil/FSharpType.fs

Comment: @PhillipTrelford  (and luksan) Can you CC this onto the other Q plz - this Q is on the verge of being VTCd (I hope)

Comment: No, this is not currently possible. But it is [a proposed improvement for F# language](http://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/5663267-allow-to-generate-dus-and-records-in-type-provider). If you want to see this feature in future versions of  F# - please vote.