# Can a type provider be used to generate a type extension?

Tags: f#, type-providers

I have a record type

```
type Foo = {mutable x:int; mutable y:int}
```

and I want to auto generate a `clone` function for it:-

```
type Foo with
  member m.clone() = {x=m.x;y=m.y}
```

Is it possible to generate this type extension using a type provider?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? That would be the same value, and since the type is immutable, it would *stay* the same value.

Comment: my bad, added mutable keywords.

Comment: Unfortunately support for metaprogramming is a bit... Restricted - both in C# and F#. It's a pre-alpha-can-do-anything stage, but the [mixin type provider shown here](https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/6159-meta-programming-madness-with-the-mixin-type-provider) can actually generate code for you and it could be one of many reasonable use cases.

Comment: You cannot generate record type from type provider: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20421160/providing-a-discriminated-union-from-an-f-type-provider
If it is possible to have Foo as a plain class you can generate new class with clone method based on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't define C#-style extension members or F#-style augmentations via type providers.

Support for provided C#-style extension members was attempted for F# 4.0, but was ultimately cut. You can follow that discussion [here](https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/dsyme/cleanup/contribution/7773), then [here](https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/dsyme/cleanup/contribution/7780).